# Cannot start Eclipse RCP application created by maven + tycho

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, xtext, tycho

I observed the following problem.
In case distribution of Eclipse RCP application that created by standard feature in Eclipse IDE starts with out problem
In case the same application created by maven scripts it fails with error

```
!SESSION 2017-09-13 13:32:10.129 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_131
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-13 13:32:12.185
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

I provided some investigation and found out that config.ini file is not created correctly. Some root plugin is not marked with flag start.
These are :
- org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.12.0.v20160606-1342.jar
- org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.8.0.v20160509-1230.jar
- org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar
- org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.3.200.v20160324-1850.jar
- org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.3.400.v20160506-0750.jar

Could you please suggest me the possible reason of this issue?
Are there way to configure generating config.ini correctly?

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: The following section has to be added to product definition   <configurations>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
   </configurations>

Comment: so issue resolved.

Comment: Hello Alexander,
great that you solved your issue by yourself. Please share the solution by answering the question yourself (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and not in a comment. By doing this you can also remove the "RESOLVED" from the title. As it is not the proper way to mark resolved questions on Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue. This is:
The following section has to be added to product definition

```
<configurations>
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
  <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
</configurations>
```

Commonly speaking this portion of XML defines which plugin shall be started automatically while your application is being started. Product definition is file that intended to description target eclipse application. For example:

https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Ffile_wizards%2Fnew_product_config.htm